# E: Impossible de trouver le paquet minicom

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-sources

I want install minicom and other package n ubuntu 12.04 baut I have this result:

```
rimeh@rimeh-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minicom
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait 
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet minicom
```

and my sources.list is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [How do I restore the default repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories).

After that do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And [install Minicom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom) by tuping:

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```